# SQL connection forcibly closed while receiving results

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been having some connectivity issues recently with my website. And today I finally received SOME idea as to what the issue may be. I got this error message while trying to log in.

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

So the question is, what could be causing this error message to get generated?

This only ever seems to occur under high user load. CPU, RAM, and network traffic do not seem to be maxed out.

Comment: There are probably other messages as well. Look in the server error log, too. Corruption can cause this.

Comment: I can almost guarantee the error is caused by improperly handling the connections in your code base.  Post an example of how you make your DB calls.  Essentially, it's highly likely the connection pool is dropping connections because you are orphaning them.

Comment: Are you still interested in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error very very often occurs straight after you have had a connection break (e.g. the server terminated the connection, your server process had the KILL command run against it or the network connection between you and the server was broken), and especially if your client is using connection pooling in those circumstances.

So try looking at what happened prior to the error you're seeing.

Comment: So this message would get returned if the process thread took too long to execute and IIS terminated it?

Comment: I haven't seen it in that scenario, more often it's when the SQL Server itself kills the process. I'm not saying this is the only way it happens, but just one way.